# Possible to access a typedef declared within a class declaration?

Tags: c++, typedef

I'm writing a program in C++ and an external header file I'm using makes very liberal use of typedefs within class declarations.

So, when I go to lookup the return type of a function, I'll see `GlobalVariableList FooBar()`, but then to actually store the type it returns, I can't just use `GlobalVariableType` because its a typedef of `iplist<GlobalVariabl>` declared within the class I'm referencing in the header file.

Is it possible access a class's typedef declared within it at all from outside of the class?

Comment: Depends on whether the typedef is public. Also, `auto` is your friend.

Comment: @T.C. the typedef is in the public section, so yea... and yea but you can't use auto for everything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it if the typedef is public

```
class foo
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<bar> barContainer;
//...
}

foo::barContainer
```

Comment: Ah, this works! I swear I tried this and it didn't work, but I think when I tried that I used the wrong name or something.

Answer (score 2):

```
 classname::typedefname
```

should work like a charm; GNU Radio does this all over the place:

[basic_block](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gnuradio-runtime/lib/basic_block.cc#L45)

```
basic_block::basic_block(const std::string &name,
    io_signature::sptr input_signature,
    io_signature::sptr output_signature)
```

[io_signature](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gnuradio-runtime/include/gnuradio/io_signature.h#L45)

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<io_signature> sptr;
```